# Store user's images in a web application

Tags: database, web-applications, storage, file-storage

I have a web application currently being developed in JSP/Servlets.
The application allows users to **upload** image files for each user account.

**What is the best way to store the images?**
Please consider the following features that I'd like to have before your answer;

1. I am using MySQL now, but there could be a possibility of moving to a different database.
2. I can store the images as flat files, but I want the `admin` account to have an option to **backup the complete database** and reload it later. Ideally the backup/reload should work with the images too. (even if the backup was done from a different physical machine and reload was done from a different machine)
3. Using BLOB/CLOB is an option that solves problem 2.
   But, **what if my database becomes very large**?

Comment: Related: [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store them in the file system.  It's faster and simpler.  Often, when accessing an image, you're going to have to save it to a file anyway before you can utilize it.  You can examine the images with third party tools. You can store the recordID in the filename to keep the image/record association from ever being broken.

Many others share this opinion: http://forums.asp.net/p/1512925/3610536.aspx

Answer (score 6):

In your case, I strongly recommend you having a `blob` field on your database and store the images in it. Mainly, because this **is** the correct place for them. So, make a Servlet that retrieves the image of the specified user from the database. For example, `/userimage?name=john`.

About your "size/performance" problem:

- Databases were made (among other things) to store and exchange **large amounts of data**.
  So, **they're the best option**.
- Even if you store them on other sites, they will still reduce free space and performance.
- If you **really** want to manage LARGE data (>= 3TB, not your case) then you can store them on a file system and save the filenames in the DB. For more info, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay).

Answer (score -2):

Just store them in the DB... if your user base "becomes very large" you'll have buckets of cash to buy a balls-out database server (or even a farm of them) which can handle the load, now won't you?